# ¿porque manda error cuando quiero iniciar el servidor?

Tags: laravel

clone un repo de laravel pero a la hora de ejecutarlo manda errores instale las dependencias que pedia para poder ejecutarlo pero una vez mas manda error en la terminal

Adjunto codigo:

```
´´´    public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
{
    if (! $cachePath) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
    }

    $this->files = $files;
    $this->cachePath = $cachePath;
}´´´
```

el error lo da en lo que esta dentro del if la verdad no se que sea soy primerizo en laravel

Adjunto imagen de la terminal:

[image: ese error manda en la terminal y pone que dentro del if esta error la verdad no se que sea apenas estoy conociendo laravel no se si sea algo de las variables de entorno o que pueda ser]

Comment: Yo miraría el fichero `conf/cache.php` puede que algo falte ahí.
Y repasaría el fichero `.env`
Parece que estás generando la key, siempre puedes hacerlo a mano...

Comment: segun esto faltaba el archivo env pero lo inclui y puse todo lo que va dentro y aun asi manda ese error

Comment: El error parece de vistas, o sea al convertir los Blades a PHP.
¿estará el fallo en con/view.php? Compará el fichero con el original de Laravel. En mi proyecto actual, me acabo de dar cuenta que hay el path de las rutas compiladas.